# Laravel 5.5 not working with nginx and HHVM

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, hhvm

Laravel is working fine with NGINX and PHP7 FCGI, but throwing an error `500 hphp_invoke` when using NGINX with HHVM.

When running the command `tail -n 50 -f /var/log/hhvm/error.log` the output is:
`Fatal error: syntax error, unexpected '(' in /var/www/apps/erp.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/LoadEnvironmentVariables.php on line 41`

It is a fresh Laravel install and anything has not been changed.

I also tested hello world php scripts with NGINX and HHVM and they are working fine.

I am using ubuntu 16.04

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why would you use HHVM anyway? It has no advantages since release of PHP7.
Laravel 5.5 is also moved to PHP7, so there a high possibility that it contains some syntax that HHVM just does not support.

Comment: @Danny it's not about Why use HHVM. The issue is why is there an error. You should also go through https://www.keycdn.com/blog/php-7-vs-hhvm/

Comment: HHVM was in Laravel 5.3 i think. Big difference between using php scripts & fully fledged framework.

Comment: "The issue is why is there an error" - because HHVM is no longer supported or compatible? From the first Google hit: "Laravel 5.3 requires PHP 5.6.4 or higher. HHVM is no longer officially supported as it does not contain the same language features as PHP 5.6+." https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade#upgrade-5.3.0